# react-native-push-notification foreground notification

Tags: react-native

I am developing an app via react native.
I need send some data with push notifications but in android when I receive notification its show in the screen.
I configured notifications like below:

```
PushNotification.configure({

    onRegister: function(token) {
        Fetcher("userSetNotifToken",{notifToken:token.token},true);

    },
    onNotification: function(notification) {
        console.log(notification);
        if(platform  == 'ios') {
            if (notification.alert.extra !== undefined && notification.alert.extra.type == 'trip') {
                alert("sad");
            }
            notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
        }else{
            if (notification.data !== undefined && notification.data.type == 'trip') {
                Actions.reset("home", {trip: notification.data.trip});
            }
        }
    },
    senderID: "----",
    permissions: {alert: true, badge: true, sound: true},
    popInitialNotification: false,
    requestPermissions: true,
});
```

Is there any way to disable this option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution
in node_modules folder under the react-native-push-notification folder :

> java/com/dieam/reactnativepushnotification/modules/RNPushNotificationListenerService.java

i changed this :

```
pushNotificationHelper.sendToNotificationCentre(bundle);
```

to this :

```
if (!isForeground) {
pushNotificationHelper.sendToNotificationCentre(bundle);
}
```

Comment: You probably don’t want to be editing files in your node_modules. If for any reason you have to remove your node_modules folder and reinstall your dependencies all your changes will be lost. Better to fork the repo, make the changes and use your fork. Or find a way to make the change via your app code.

Comment: Did you find any solution without modifying node_modules?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still the easiest approach today. I patched this file and used https://github.com/ds300/patch-package to create a persistent patch for my team.

Answer (score 0):

Updated as per version 6.1.3
Add this inside `application` in AndroidManifest.xml.
https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/master/example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <service
      android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
      android:exported="false" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
  </service>

  <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground"
              android:value="false"/>
  <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
              android:resource="@android:color/white"/>
</application>
```